# .htaccess is not forcing my url to https.?

Tags: apache

I do not have know-how regarding `.htaccess` with multiple websites. I have two websites on the same domain: one is in a subfolder and one is in a subdomain. The one in the subdomain is a WordPress website, so it doing a great job of redirecting itself to HTTPS. My subfolder website, which is on custom PHP, is not redirecting to HTTPS. Even after reading some hosting providers topics regarding this, I am not able to make the URL force to HTTPS.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?subfolder/(.*) https://%www.study-material.info/v2/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN custum php 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?subfolder/(.*) https://%www.study-material.info/v2/$1 [R,L]
# END custum php

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

Comment: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssl/how-to-force-https-using-the-htaccess-file, https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747758-Force-your-site-to-load-securely-with-an-htaccess-file, https://www.siteground.com/kb/how-to-force-ssl-with-htaccess/, https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-https-littlebizzy/ ....I can keep going....

Comment: i have took guide from them but after doing nothing get change. my domain name is www.study-material.info subfolder is v2 complete url is www.study-material.info/v2